# mysql join table - selecting the newest row

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

I have the following two MySQL tables

**TABLE NAMES**

```
NAME_ID   NAME
1         name1
2         name2
3         name3
```

**TABLE STATUS**

```
STATUS_ID    NAME_ID     TIMESTAMP
1            1           2010-12-20 12:00
2            2           2010-12-20 10:00
3            3           2010-12-20 10:30
4            3           2010-12-20 14:00
```

I would like to select all info from table **NAMES** and add most recent correspondent **TIMESTAMP** column from table **STATUS**

**RESULT**

```
NAME_ID NAME     TIMESTAMP
1       name1    2010-12-20 12:00
2       name2    2010-12-20 10:00
3       name3    2010-12-20 14:00
```

Am stuck on this one.
How do I left join only on the newer timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query :

```
select n.NAME_ID ,  n.NAME , max(TIMESTAMP) as time from NAMES n left join 
STATUS s on s.NAME_ID = n.NAME_ID group by n.NAME_ID
```

Comment: I like your answer. It's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Just a little change...

SELECT `names`.`ID`,MAX(`status`.`date`) AS `datecre`
FROM `names`,`status`
WHERE `names`.`ID` = `names`.`name_ID`
GROUP BY `names`.`ID`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_names tn
LEFT JOIN
        table_status ts
ON      ts.status_id = 
        (
        SELECT  status_id
        FROM    table_status tsi
        WHERE   tsi.name_id = tn.name_id
        ORDER BY
                name_id DESC, TIMESTAMP DESC, status_id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

This will handle duplicates correctly.

Create an index on `table_status (name_id, timestamp, status_id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: Sounds too complicated. "Haim Evgi" answer above looks cleaner and makes sense. What do you think?

Comment: @cmancre: if you don't need other values from `table_status` except `timestamp`, then Haim's solution is nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    status.*
FROM
    status
        JOIN
            (SELECT name_id, MAX(timestamp)AS latest FROM status GROUP BY name_id) AS sub 
            ON (status.name_id = sub.name_id AND status.timestamp = sub.latest);
```